# Removing Commas between Hashtags on WordPress on Astra theme

Tags: themes

I have tried all possible ways to remove the (commas ,) between the tags on my Wordpress website but I haven't had any luck.

URL: https://www.content-whale.com/blog/

[image]

PHP

```php
add_filter('the_tags', 'remove_tag_commas', 10, 2);

function remove_tag_commas($tags, $post_id) {
$tags_string = implode(', ', $tags); // Convert tags array to a comma-separated string
$tags_string = str_replace(', ,', ',', $tags_string); // Remove consecutive commas

// Convert the modified string back to an array of tags
$modified_tags = explode(', ', $tags_string);

return $modified_tags;
}
```

OR

Javascript

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.premium-blog-post-tags-container'); const tags = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('.premium-blog-post-tags-container a[rel]'));

tags.forEach((tag, index) => { tag.textContent = tag.textContent.replace(/,\s*/g, '');

if (index !== tags.length - 1) { const comma = tag.nextSibling; if (comma && comma.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && comma.textContent.trim() === ',') { comma.remove(); } } });
```

If I modify theme what do I do exactly.

Comment: answering this here may not be possible, that site uses a lot of Elementor templating, and I can't see any of the standard WordPress markup for tag blocks/lists/clouds where those commas appear. You should go to an Elementor community or an Astra community to ask this as questions about 3rd party plugins and themes are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: further research suggests this is a feature of the premium addons for elementor plugin, and it's using `the_tags`, do you have other filters that try to hide tags or tags that have a blank name? What you're showing is not normal. I also tried to edit your question to make the code blocks readable, a lot of the PHP was mangled and smushed on to a single line as well

Comment: I found the solution on StackOverflow. But thanks for your assistance

Comment: hmm I see you asked this over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606142/removing-commas-between-hashtags-on-wordpress-on-astra-theme though it got some downvotes. It doesn't look like you found a solution to prevent this, but you did find code to hide commas